# Android email app with attachment not working

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I'm trying to develop email app and I want to attach a image to it, but I'm getting `NullPointerException`. Here's my code:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
attachmentfile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

Log.e("Attachment Path: ", attachmentfile);
URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentfile);
cursor.close();`
```

Please help me

Comment: There is no requirement for any given `selectedImage` `Uri` to be something that `MediaStore` knows about, depending on where you are getting `selectedImage` from.

Comment: Improved indenting, readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not putting right the file path.

The following works for me:

```
Uri.parse("file:///"+attachmentfile));
```

Note that file path has 3 "/", the first two are for the "file://" header, the other because sdcard dir is inside the root directory of the filesystem, which is "/" in linux.